Can you use CreateML to extract text from a text blob?
I've been using CreateML to build a model via text classification. It needs to read in a blob of text, and extract a name from that text blob. (The blob is from an OCR result from an iPhone) The text blob varies in size, but the name is always present in the text.
The problem I'm having is that it will only find the name if the name has been shown during training. If it's a new name, it will not work. Is there a way I can modify CreateML to look for new names based on the other data in the blob?
If CreateML cannot do this, is there another tool that can? The resulting model needs to run on an iPhone.
